# Export to Excel gives error for large lists

Tags: export, excel

This is my data [mwedata.dat](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4tcwo2ZvQCRaHRCVlY0bTNPR2M)

I do this:

```
mwe = Import["mwedata.dat"];
dataforexcel20 = DeleteCases[mwe, a_ /; a[[3]] > 20];
dataforexcel80 = DeleteCases[mwe, a_ /; a[[3]] > 80];

Dimensions[dataforexcel80]
Dimensions[dataforexcel20]

{48011, 6}
{2384, 6}

Export["mwe20.xlsx", dataforexcel20]
"mwe20.xlsx"

Export["mwe80.xlsx", dataforexcel80]
$Failed
```

The Export works for the smaller file but not the larger file. The error message says

```
Export::fmterr: "Invalid \!\(\"XLS\"\) format. "
```

When I do this

```
Table[dataforexcel[k] = DeleteCases[mwe, a_ /; a[[3]] != k], {k, 1,100}];
Table[Export["mwetest.xlsx", dataforexcel[k]], {k, 1, 100}]
```

I get

```
{"mwetest.xlsx", "mwetest.xlsx", "mwetest.xlsx",   "mwetest.xlsx" ....}
```

and so on a 100 times. So there is nothing wrong with the data when `a[[3]]>20`

In a unrelated question, when doing an `Export` inside the Table.. would it have been possible to index the excel files with `k`?

```
 Table[Export["mwetest[k].xlsx", dataforexcel[k]], {k, 1, 100}]
```

Ok.. back to my earlier problem, I thought that excel could handle up to 65,000 rows. I'd appreciate some help in figuring out what I am doing wrong here or what can I do to fix  my `Export` of a large file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem like a solution that's too easy to be true, but I tried the following:

```
Export["mwe80.xls", dataforexcel80]
```

It worked for me -  the Excel document got exported quickly.  I think that the problem was in the [format](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-xls-and-xlsx/), as the error said.

**EDIT**

As to your second question, the code you're looking for involves `StringJoin`:

```
 Table[Export["mwetest["<>ToString[k]<>"].xlsx", dataforexcel[k]], {k, 1, 100}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you have a sense of why this is working for *.xls but not for *.xlsx ?

Comment: I can't honestly say why one format works.  `.xlsx` should be able to support $2^{20}$ entries, which is even more than its `.xls` predecessor, but if I had to hazard a guess, I'd say that Mathematica's `Export` function is at fault here.  In the docs the suggested spreadsheet extension is `.xls`, so perhaps the `Export` function was built around that.